# How to store output command in variable and use this varible again for next command after pipe

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, parted

How to store output command in a variable and use this variable again for next command after pipe?

```
lsblk | awk {'print $1'} | grep ^sd | parted $input mklable gpt mkpart primary "1 -1" -s
```

`$input` is output `lsblk | awk {'print $1'} | grep ^sd` command and use `$input`
again in `parted` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
dev=$(lsblk | awk '$1 ~ /^sd/ {print $1; exit}')
if [ -n "$dev" ]; then
  dev=/dev/$dev
  parted "$dev" mklabel gpt mkpart primary "1 -1" -s
fi
```

Now, if you want the first `sd?` disk, it may be easier to do:

```
shopt -s nullglob; set -- /dev/sd[a-z]
if (($# > 0 )); then
  parted "$1" mklabel gpt mkpart primary "1 -1" -s
fi
```

Or to do it for every disk:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for dev in /dev/sd[a-z]; do
  (set -x; parted "$dev" mklabel gpt mkpart primary "1 -1" -s)
done
```

Comment: How to use this command in a terminal line?

Answer (score 0):

Just save to a variable and process it.

```
input=$(lsblk | awk {'print $1'} | grep ^sd); \
parted $input mklabel gpt mkpart primary "1 -1" -s
```